smartgwt toolstripbutton disable while clickhandler method is working
Using Java I have declared a toolstripbutton object with this properties:
ToolStripButton loButtons[] = new ToolStripButton[1];
loButtons[0] = new ToolStripButton("Finish Task");

loButtons[0].setAutoFit(true);

loButtons[0].addClickHandler(new ClickHandler() 

{
   public void onClick(ClickEvent poEvent) 
   {
      loButtons[0].disable();

      actionToCloseTask();

      sendNotificationEmail();   

      loButtons[0].enable();
   }
});

When the button is push, the task is finish, a notification email is send and the task disappear from the main panel, but while the methods inside the clickhandler are happening, the user is enabled to push the button many times, causing a lot of notifications
I have tried to avoid this actions with disable and enable the button, but this doesn't work.
I would like to get a suggestion about this problem, or an idea to disable the button's action while this button is working whit the first request.
Thank you.
